# Resize UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiscrollview

I am creating an app like the "PageControl" from apple.
An scrollview with another scrollview inside for each page.

```
UIScrollView * scrollForPage = [[UIScrollView alloc]init];  
    scrollForPage.pagingEnabled = NO;
    scrollForPage.contentSize = CGSizeMake(mainScroll.frame.size.width, 200 + mainScroll.frame.size.height+150);
    scrollForPage.autoresizingMask =  ( UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
    scrollForPage.clipsToBounds = YES;

    CGRect frame = mainScroll.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
    frame.origin.y = 0;

    CGRect frame2 = frame;
    frame2.origin.x = 0;
    frame2.origin.y = 0;

    controller.view.frame = frame2;
    scrollForPage.frame = frame;


    [scrollForPage addSubview:controller.view];

    [mainScroll addSubview:scrollForPage];
    [scrollForPage release];
```

however my controller´s view have an dynamic size, how can I resize the "scrollForPage" to have the same size??

Thanks

Comment: I have a single doubt: What exactly is the "controller"? Is it the ViewController? The parent ScrollView?

Comment: it is the ViewController, the view foreach "page" of the main scrollView

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?
You set pagingEnabled to NO but you are referring to pages. 
The size of your scrollView should remain constant even if the size of the views within the content of the scroll view may have dynamic sizes and therefore may force you to change the size of the content of the scroll view.

So what exactly is it?

Comment: the paging enable is YES, just for the main Scrollview, inside that, the scrollForPage is NO. i have alway the same size for the scrollForPage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code to detect the size of a view is this:

```
CGRect screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

Just make the frame of the scroll view equal to screenSize, and call the above line often.

Comment: it isn t working,  have the same behave.. i made this changes :

Comment: (code)   CGRect screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
screenSize.origin.x=frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
scrollForPage.frame = screenSize;   (code)